# Unable to autofill textarea based on selected datalist option

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to autofill Address of the client in textarea based on input of client name in input field.
I made a 'for loop' to get datalist of the clients name. And for address i  fetched 'id' of selected option using javascript so that i can use it to get address of selected client's name to put it in "$index" part of "$clientdata[$index]['client_city_town"].

Now how can i put "clientid" in php's "$index" so that i could get autofilled textarea on option selection.
If any other solution please suggest.

My code :

HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
   <p>
    <span class="text-dark" style="font-weight: 500"> To : </span>
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="clientName" list="clients-list" size="40" required="required">
     @if( !empty( $client_data ) )
     <datalist id="clients-list">
       @for($i=0; $i < count($client_data); $i++)
           <option value="{{$client_data[$i]['client_name']}}" id="{{$client_data[$i]['id']}}"></option>
         @endfor
       </datalist>
     @endif
      <br>
      <textarea type="text" id="clientAddress"> {{$client_data[$index]['client_city_town']}}</textarea>
     </p>


</div>
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
$('#clientName').on('change', function() {
    var clientname = $(this).val();
    var clientid = $('#clients-list option[value=' + clientname +']').attr('id');

});
```

Array used ($client_data):

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [client_name] => John Doe
            [client_shop_street] => Baker Street
            [client_city_town] => California
            [client_pincode] => 
            [client_desc] => hello1
            [client_contact1] => 1234567890
            [client_contact2] => 1111111111
            [client_email] => 
            [client_total_amt] => 45000
            [client_paid_amt] => 37000
            [created_at] => 
            [updated_at] => 2021-06-21 18:39:54
            [created_by] => 1
        )

[1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [client_name] =>  Tom Jerry
            [client_shop_street] => Wall Street
            [client_city_town] => New York
            [client_pincode] => 
            [client_desc] => testing demo
            [client_contact1] => 2222222222
            [client_contact2] => 3333333333
            [client_email] => 
            [client_total_amt] => 45000
            [client_paid_amt] => 37000
            [created_at] => 
            [updated_at] => 2021-06-21 23:32:12
            [created_by] => 1
        )
)
```

Comment: wheres the javascript ?

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik I have updated the code and shared javascript. Please suggest some solution. I am stuck

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the [.val()](https://api.jquery.com/val/) method to add data to the `textarea`. Something like the below :-

```js
$(function() {
    
  let textForTextArea = '';
  
    $('#ice-cream-choice').on('change', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    textForTextArea = `${textForTextArea} ${e.target.value}`
    $('#all-that-is-selected').val(textForTextArea)
  })
  
})
```

```css
label , input {
  display : block;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="ice-cream-choice">Choose a flavor:</label>
<input list="ice-cream-flavors" id="ice-cream-choice" name="ice-cream-choice" />

<datalist id="ice-cream-flavors">
    <option value="Chocolate">
    <option value="Coconut">
    <option value="Mint">
    <option value="Strawberry">
    <option value="Vanilla">
</datalist>

<textarea name="" id="all-that-is-selected" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
```