# "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier" in Console

Tags: javascript

I want to pass php variable to javascript variable.
When i click on error, it gives a redline under "console.log(data)"
But it throws the error in Console Window -

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

I am new to Javascript.

Javascript:

```
<script>
$('#clientName').on('change', function() {
    var clientname = $(this).val();
    var clientid = $('#clients-list option[value=' + clientname +']').attr('id');

    var data = [];
    data = <?= $client_data ?>
    console.log(data);
});
</script>
```

PHP Variable ( $client_data ) :

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [client_name] => John Doe
            [client_shop_street] => Baker Street
            [client_city_town] => California
            [client_pincode] => 
            [client_desc] => hello1
            [client_contact1] => 1234567890
            [client_contact2] => 1111111111
            [client_email] => 
            [client_total_amt] => 45000
            [client_paid_amt] => 37000
            [created_at] => 
            [updated_at] => 2021-06-21 18:39:54
            [created_by] => 1
        )

[1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [client_name] =>  Tom Jerry
            [client_shop_street] => Wall Street
            [client_city_town] => New York
            [client_pincode] => 
            [client_desc] => testing demo
            [client_contact1] => 2222222222
            [client_contact2] => 3333333333
            [client_email] => 
            [client_total_amt] => 45000
            [client_paid_amt] => 37000
            [created_at] => 
            [updated_at] => 2021-06-21 23:32:12
            [created_by] => 1
        )
)
```

Comment: Does it say which line number it is?

Comment: Instead of trying to render spaghetti from the server, you might make an ajax call to PHP to fetch the data.

Comment: Could you share what is generated by PHP? E.g. if this is in `index.php`, you can execute the php script from terminal or by using a web browser and viewing the page source. 

When PHP prints the client data, it is coming out in a format that isn't valid JavaScript

Comment: @alexanderbird. This is what i am trying to achieve using php - https://stackoverflow.com/q/68284371/15360495

Comment: @steveo314  It redirecting me to the line that shows like this :
data = [{"id":1,"client_name": John Doe, 'client_shop_street': .........}];

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I pass variables and data from PHP to JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740548/how-do-i-pass-variables-and-data-from-php-to-javascript)

Comment: @steveo314 When i click on line no. it shows Redline under console.log(data) in the file.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[Solved] Single Quotes missed around PHP Code.

```
<script>
$('#clientName').on('change', function() {
    var clientname = $(this).val();
    var clientid = $('#clients-list option[value=' + clientname +']').attr('id');

    var data = [];
    data = '<?php echo json_encode($client_data) ?>'
    console.log(data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Two problems in the code:

1. Use `json_encode` when using a PHP array as a value for a JS variable.

   ```
    data = <?json_encode($client_data) ?>
   ```
2. I believe it should be `console.log(data)`

Comment: I used json_encode() but shows same error.

Comment: When i click on error, it gives a redline under "console.log(data)"

Comment: Aren't you running this in a browser ?

Comment: I am running it in Chrome, and this error is in console

Comment: Removed a typo in the answer `data = <?json_encode($client_data) ?>`. Try now.

Comment: Thank you for your help. 
But i missed something - and it worked - I missed the single quotes i.e data = '<?php echo json_encode($client_data) ?>'

Answer (score 0):

You'd want to use `json_encode` as mentioned above, but you're also missing the semicolon at the end of your data variable.

```
var data = <?= json_encode($client_data) ?>;  // <- ;
console.log(data);
```

Without the semicolon you're doing something like this

```
data = <?= $client_data ?> console.log(data);
```

Answer (score -1):

To expose a PHP object in a format that makes sense in JavaScript, you'll need to encode it in a JavaScript-friendly format. The simplest is to use json, which can be interpreted by JavaScript without any special parsing.

In your PHP file:

```
<script>
$('#clientName').on('change', function() {
    var clientname = $(this).val();
    var clientid = $('#clients-list option[value=' + clientname +']').attr('id');

    var data = [];
    data = <?= json_encode($client_data) ?>
    console_data(data);
});
</script>
```

`json_encode` [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Comment: It gives same error even after using json_encode().

Comment: When i click on error, it gives a redline under "console.log(data)"